# How to set up shared pdf printer on home network

Tags: 20.04, printing, samba, pdf, sharing

Is there a step by step procedure to set up a shared pdf printer on 20.04?

I have installed a cups pdf printer which works fine on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop host.

From the GUI >> Printers >> Additional Printer Settings my pdf printer is shared. The Device URI: = cups-pdf:/ But I do not see this printer from a Windoze (sic) or other 20.04 PCs on my network or from Android phones or networked iPads.

I know that I may need to change setting in:

```
/etc/cups/cupsd.conf
/etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf
/etc/samba/smb.conf
```

and possibly access:

```
https://pcname_or_IP:631/admin
```

But I have not found any procedures that works or make sense.

Is there a simple method using the GUI?

Is there a step by step published?

I have looked at https://www.steveroot.co.uk/virtual-pdf-printer-for-our-small-office-network-a-step-by-step-how-to.html but it does more than I need.

I am looking print to pdf at home from mobiles, iPads and Windoze clients.

Output from:

```
sudo cupsctl
  
_debug_logging=0
_remote_admin=0
_remote_any=0
_share_printers=0
_user_cancel_any=0
BrowseLocalProtocols=dnssd
DefaultAuthType=Basic
JobPrivateAccess=default
JobPrivateValues=default
MaxLogSize=0
PageLogFormat=
SubscriptionPrivateAccess=default
SubscriptionPrivateValues=default
WebInterface=Yes
```

Comment: You misspelled "Windows"

Comment: Give the output of `sudo cupsctl`.

Answer (score 2):

> From the GUI >> Printers >> Additional Printer Settings my pdf printer is shared.

This provides the **potential** for the sharing of that **particular** printer to take place. But the printing system has to cooperate with your intention. At present, cupsctl shows `_share_printers=0`. Use `cupsctl --share-printers` to change this to `_share_printers=1`.

Comment: That seems to work.  Had to fiddle about with the driver for some reason.  I am struggling still with various clients on my home network.  iPads seem to work.  Will check out other clients including: Android, Ubuntu 20.04 and Windoze (sic) 10.  PDFs are arriving in ~/PDF which is fine for me.  But not sure how this is specified.  I am not sure where path = /var/spool/cups-pdf/out features in my /etc/samba/smb.conf

Comment: Where the PDFs end up may be specified in */etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf*. The default suits me. I am unfamiliar with smb.